# How can I reach JSF @Singleton Bean from inside @SessionScoped Bean and vice versa?

Tags: java, jsf, singleton, session-bean

My purpose is to have a @Singleton class which runs automated scheduled methods throughout the application on a cloud server. But I also have @SessionScoped beans which I would like to communicate with.
Is it possible to reach a @SessionScoped bean if I'm not in a user's web-session and the reverse: How can I use my @Singleton Bean as a user from my session?

Thanks and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

You can reach Singleton Bean in SessionScoped Bean using application context to get Singleton bean or maybe injection in SessionScoped Bean.

```
context.getBean(SomeSingletonClass.class)
```

To do the reverse, there is no good way, you can put sessions in list of WeakReference inside se Singleton bean.